# Codeigniter - HTML not getting rendered

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have deployed my PHP application built on Codeigniter. When I call the root URL, browser is successfully redirected to login view but not HTML is rendered.

What can be the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML is not rendered?" Do you mean that RAW HTML is being shown in the browser?

Comment: By "HTML is not rendered", I mean that nothing is shown in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Did you deploy it to a different computer than your development machine. Maybe you are using "nice urls" and the target server does not allow url rewriting with htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to the way you load views.

- Loading a view this way sends it straight to a browser:

  ```
  $this->load->view('foo_view.php', $data);
  ```
- But if you have an optional, third, parameter set to TRUE, it will return data as a string so you have to echo it:

  ```
  echo $this->load->view('foo_view.php', $data, TRUE);
  ```

More info at the bottom of [this CI User Guide page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html).

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is being shown in the browser it is worth checking the following:

1. system/cache is writeable
2. system/logs is writeable
3. GZIP compression is disabled in application/config/config.php
4. telnet port 80 and see what you get back, any headers?
5. [**tail the logs**](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2009/02/Watch-CodeIgniter-errors-reported-as-they-happen) to watch for errors

Answer (score 0):

There should be proper deployment otherwise you are bound to see issues. This may prove helpful to you.

[Deploying CodeIgniter (or any PHP projects) to the live site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011363/deploying-codeigniter-or-any-php-projects-to-the-live-site)