# Transfering site from demo server to live server

Tags: php, file-upload, server-migration

mostly i come across a situation where i have to move files between two servers. I usually test my project live in one testing server online and client checks the websties functionality and all. After completing all the task i again have to transfer the contents of the testing server to the live server along with data too...

So for that process i download all the files uploaded by client in the testing server, backup database and again upload the database to new server and client files too. if the client has uploaded less files then it is no prob but in case of large files i really waste my time copying files from one to next.

so how can i make the same process in less time even with large files

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is your preferred php deployment strategy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425692/what-is-your-preferred-php-deployment-strategy)

Comment: some what similar to that one but with small diff that my client enters his complete site data and completes the whole site with actual data in my testing site. it inculdes writing page contents and other stuffs

Answer (score 0):

We use SVN which is hosted on our server.

When we want to port the site to a test area we have a test domain name setup which is hosted on the server, and we can just run `svn update` on a subdomain and it will just copy all of the files across.

When we go live assuming the domain is hosted on the same server we just run `svn update` on that folder as well. Very quick and easy.

Comment: I dun have SVN Hosted in my server

Comment: @KoolKabin - SVN is free. You can also try Git or some other version management. @fire - This is ok, except it doesn't allow for test data, since both use the same DB.

Comment: sorry for my english... i meant to say that my hosting server has svn hosted or not i don't know. So how would i know that and if not installed can i install it there?