# Are there any tools for automatically moving from testing to production servers?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, production-environment

Are there any tools for automatically moving code from testing to (stage and then to) production?
We are running on a LAMP stack and don't want to rely on FTP access?
Other than that, is there some BASH or PERL script out there for this same process?
Our production servers cannot run SVN or HG which we use for development.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is your preferred php deployment strategy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425692/what-is-your-preferred-php-deployment-strategy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [PHING](http://www.phing.info).  It's very flexible and you can extend it with raw php code if you need to...  It does (and can do) a whole lot more than just moving things around (including testing, building, documenting, etc)...

As for the file-transfering bit, you can connect to the remote server using a bunch of built in methods (including but not limited to FTP, SCP, SFTP, RSYNC, and more)...

Comment: +1 I completely agree...
Check out this recent article about 10 php tools to make your life easier.
http://phpbuilder.com/columns/top-10-productivity-tools/Jason_Gilmore082410.php3

Answer (score 1):

You could SVN checkout the production copy onto the production server and use http?

Comment: Unfortunately, the production server cannot run SVN or HG(our VCS) because is poorly hosted.

Comment: Wait, wouldn't the better option be to get a better host then @chustar?

Comment: It would be, but for various reasons, its not an option for right now

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/index.php/Capistrano) it might be what you need, simple and doing job as you would expected.

Answer (score 1):

We use RepliWeb, it's somewhat pricy, but extremely flexible, offers rollback capability, notifications, task execution, scheduled moves, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

webistrano for a pretty UI for managing capistrano