# Using Apache ANT to deploy web applications?

Tags: php, deployment, ant

I was just able to get Apache ANT running on my computer. The `ant -version` commando outputs the version number , verifying that the installation went well.

I have read that [ANT is well suited to handle deployment](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/09/16/) of web applications including PHP projects and have spent some time to get it working, but I just can't get my head around how to set it up to sync my files to my web server.

**How can I make ANT sync `folderA` with `folderB` ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Last time I checked (long ago) there was no remote sync task in Ant (only [local](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sync.html)). You would have to [write a shell script that calls rsync](http://topecoders.blogspot.com/2010/04/remote-deployment-with-ant-and-rsync.html) and [execute](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasksoverview.html#exec) this from Ant instead. There is a number of [remote tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasksoverview.html#remote) though. And you could check out your code from your [VCS](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasksoverview.html#scm) instead of syncing it to the server.

On a sidenote, you might want to consider [Phing](http://phing.info) over Ant. It's a port of Ant to PHP. It has a [FileSync Task](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2008/07/21/filesynctask-using-phing-to-synchronize-files-and-directories/). You can also add your own Tasks (written in PHP) and is commonly used in Continuous Integration servers for PHP.

Also see [What is your preferred Deployment Strategy for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425692/what-is-your-preferred-php-deployment-strategy) and a [couple others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=deployment+php).

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual: http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html
Look at the <copy> task.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do the same and just came across this article on how to deploy using ant, maybe it'll give you a different way of going about it: [Deploying using Ant](http://www.developer.com/open/article.php/998241)