# Can I use composer to deploy my Github Repositories into my projects and change some lines of code

Tags: php, github, composer-php

I'm a little unexperienced with composer and I'm starting to use Github more and more. I'm a php developer and I an application to serve as a CMS/Backoffice of the websites I develop to my clients.

I'm using and HMVC framework and I wanted to know if its possible o deploy a module (a repository) in a specific folder with composer, and again with composer change some lines of code.

For example, I have this structure:

```
- app
-- modules
--- users
--- auth
-- index.php
-- configs.php
- public
-- assets
```

In this example, `users` and `auth` are booth a module. Imagine that I have this repository in rafaelmsantos/posts and want to deploy it on the `modules` folder. That part I guess is simple, or its difficult?

The second part is the following: imagine that in `posts` repository I have a class file like this:

```
<?php 
    // $this->route('posts', 'postsController->action');

    class PostsController extends appController{

        function action(){
            somestuff();
        }

    }
```

And when I deploy the module, I want the composer to read this file and detect that comment above class declaration and insert it into `config.php` that is in same level that `modules` folder.

Is this possible too?

Let me know some good tutorials for composer or something. 
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, composer is designated for something else: it is a package manager, and not a tool for deployment. If you are looking to deploy your modules you might want to take a look into Bamboo, or search other Continuous integration tools. You might also be interested in deploying PHP apps with Apache Ant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226871/using-apache-ant-to-deploy-web-applications

Comment: Thanks @despina, I will take a look at thoose mentioned by you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer have `post-install-cmd` and `post-update-cmd` events, which must be declared in `composer.json` file in `scripts` part.
For example:

```
    {
        "scripts": {
            "post-update-cmd": "MyVendor\MyClass::postUpdate",
        }
    }
```

where 'postUpdate' is a static method, which add routes as you want.

[Full info about scripts in composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md)

Comment: With this, can I send a `post-update-cmd` to a single .php file containing the magic to add routes? (non english native :s)

Comment: "A script, in Composer's terms, can either be a PHP callback (defined as a static method) or any command-line executable command" (https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#what-is-a-script-)

So, you can declare script like this:
    `"post-update-cmd": "php /dir/to/file/script.php"`

Comment: How nice, thats exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks to you @Animir. I will give you my award in 8 hours.