# How to transfer the project to the server

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to programming field. The company which I work with has assigned me a task to develop a sample project which contains login of members and a forum. I have developed it using mysql, php and apache server. So my question is "how to transfer it onto the LMS server. Should I transfer the project from the server system itself or can I do it through my pc via internet?" My question may look very simple to ask but I am still in the learning stage. Please help me. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You need Internet connection in order to connect target server by FTP.
Also you will need to connect MySQL to push your database dump to server.

You can find more information about deployment strategy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425692/what-is-your-preferred-php-deployment-strategy).

Comment: Why are people still using FTP after all? Even back in 2001, I learned that it is very insecure, compared with other protocols...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It was informative. Thank you again..:)

Answer (score 0):

To transfer all the files you will need an ftp program and the login information for the ftp server on the LMS server.
And for the mysql it depends, the easiest way is if you have a phpMyAdmin interface for it, mot of the time you can find this @ http://thesite.com/phpMyAdmin or trough an admin panel.
Then you copy (or export) you mysql database and import it on the new server.
How you go about this exactly depends greatly from platform to platform.

Hope this helps.

To export mysql without phpMyAdmin: http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-backup-and-restore-export-and-import-mysql-databases-tutorial/

Comment: Feel free to vote up if it was :)