# Exporting files from hook in bare git repository

Tags: linux, git

So, my situation is the following: I want to maintain my website using emacs-muse mode. For transferring the website (and version control), I want to use git. So I would create a hook in the remote (bare) repository that automatically copies the HTML subdir to the web directory. How can I do that from a hook? Also note that the whole directory contains a **lot** of files, so I can't export the whole directory.

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 15):

You can use git archive, as it takes a path command. So, in your post-update hook you can do something like

```
git archive $SHA HTML | (cd dir/where/html/should/go && tar x)
```

this first creates a tarball of the subdir, and pipes that tarball to a tar command to untar it in the specified directory

Comment: That sounds good, i'm gonna try that. The only question is how to get the sha hash.

Comment: Okay, archieving HEAD works. However, archive saves "absolute" paths in relation to the git repository. However, I want to extract the files and cut the path components. How would I do that?

Comment: try using HEAD:HTML instead "HEAD HTML"

Comment: That is odd: your answer seems to be more specific and fits better jeeger's question, yet mine has more vote: +1 to fix that ;)

Answer (score 14):

(just a suggestion, as it may not be applicable in your exact configuration)

You might consider adopting this [Web-Focused Git Workflow](http://joemaller.com/2008/11/25/a-web-focused-git-workflow/) which, instead of copying, does push your repo directly on the web directory.

[image: http://joemaller.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/hub-prime2.jpg]
(From [Joe MALLER](http://joemaller.com/))

---

Less complicated:  [Using Git to maintain your website](http://dmiessler.com/blog/using-git-to-maintain-your-website) ([Daniel MIESSLER](http://danielmiessler.com/about/)):

[image: http://dmiessler.com/wp-content/uploaded_content/2008/12/git-tree.gif]

[Daniel MIESSLER](http://danielmiessler.com/about/) has an [updated version](http://danielmiessler.com/study/git/#website) of that same process:

### [image: http://danielmiessler.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/git_website_1.png]

Other suggestions are available at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-php-using-git), like this [post-update script](https://web.archive.org/web/20120427211558/http://utsl.gen.nz/git/post-update) mentioned in the [Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Unexpected_behavior).

Comment: Link to post-update script got stale in the funniest way: If I have to do fitness exercises every time I want to go through post-upgrade, I'll win the next election for governor of California ;-)

Comment: @cfi Thank you. I have restored the link.