# Git: updating website when pushing to remote repository?

Tags: git, workflow

I have a website that I'd like to update whenever I push to a remote repository. I am coming from a svn background and still trying to figure out git.

Right now, I have done the following:

- Setup a Git repository on my local machine containing the website.
- Cloned the (bare) repository to my web server.

Now I'm a bit stuck. I can push the changes to my bare repository on the server but I have no idea of how to checkout a working copy of the repository in my www directory and automatically update it whenever I push my local repository to the server. I'll probably need a hook script right?

Related question, [Deploy PHP using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-php-using-git/3387030%20Deploy%20PHP%20using%20Git), partially answers my question, but I'd like to know what the script is actually doing.

Comment: Why don't you keep a normal repository instead of a bare one on your server? And push/serve from that directly?

Comment: @Adam: I tried that initially but then when I tried to push (git push web-server), I got this error: remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me, it might work for you:
[A web-focused Git workflow](http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/)

Comment: +1 It's a neat solution but I just have to mention that it requires you to store the information twice on your host, since it involves two repositories. I know this is the trade off, just saying :)

Answer (score 5):

I found a very good (and elegant) solution for me on the [Caius Theory Website](http://caiustheory.com/automatically-deploying-website-from-remote-git-repository)

It basically starts with a bare repository and changes the worktree to the web-server folder. After that it uses a post-receive hook to update the work-tree after every push it receives. An elegant and easy to follow procedure!

Additional to the setup in that article I added a soft-linked ".git" directory from the website location back to the git repository location:

```
ln -s /home/caius/git/somesite.git/ /home/caius/vhosts/somesite.com/htdocs/.git
```

This way I can checkout another branch on the web-server by logging into it and using "git checkout " in the website folder!

I also used a slightly modification on the Python-Script "ygit-push-all.py" from [here](http://jeetworks.org/node/22) to update my multiple machines which all run the same framework code with using different config files. You could even setup a branch per server (like Demo/Development).

In addition I added the following aliases to my global git config file:

```
[alias]
    push-all = !ygit-push-all.py
    check-all = !sh -c 'git branch -r -v | grep master | awk \"{ print \\$1, \\$2 }\"'
```

**git push-all** will update *all* my remote locations

**git check-all** will show me the rev on which every remote *master* branch is

Comment: The beauty of this solution is that you can have an existing public directory (say with wordpress core files) and the bare repo can only have a subset (say /wp-content/themes/mytheme) `git checkout -f` will manage/merge the subset of tracked files (very similar a solution used by wpengine).