# git deploying project - file permissions - (chmod)

Tags: git, file-permissions, chmod

I'm deploying my project with `git` to a remote server using a post-update hook. More specifically I'm following these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git/327315#327315). Everything on my local copy has the right permissions, however after deploying with `git push production`, files that are set to `777`  change in the remote server to `-rwxr-xr-x`

I've added to both (local/remote) `.git/config` the core variables `filemode = false` and I've changed as well my umask in `/etc/profile` to `0002`

Any ideas why it keeps changing the mode of files? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `core.filemode` variable is only used when files are indexed. When git checks out files, the stored mode is used unconditionally, and files can only have a mode of 644 or 755. Modify your post-checkout hook to chmod the files.