# Bitbucket teams/organizations?

Tags: git, bitbucket

We're 5 people working on the same projects and have several GIT-repositories in Bitbucket. Each user has their own Bitbucket account. I'm looking for the best-practice approach to having some sort of team or organization feature so that we can all work on the same repositories? As a use case, when I clone a repository it's not possible for other users to push to the same repository. I hope there's some way of solving this without having everyone use the same user account.

I hope this was properly explained.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Bitbucket [just deployed their Teams feature](http://blog.bitbucket.org/2012/05/30/bitbucket-teams/), similar to GitHub's organizations.

This allows you to administer a group account without having to logout from your account and login to it.

Answer (score 4):

Update May, 30th 2012: as [Legion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62066/legion) mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10826670/6309), [Team Up with Bitbucket](http://blog.bitbucket.org/2012/05/30/bitbucket-teams/) describes the Bitbucket Teams, in order to **create a shared account**.

---

Original answer (May, 22sd 2012)

With [Bitbucket permissions](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Repository+privacy,+permissions,+and+more), you can grant write access to other users for each of your repositories.

> The user that creates a repo is known as its owner.
>   Only an owner can delete a repo. You can create unlimited Bitbucket public or private repositories.
>
> - A public repository is visible to all bitbucket users.
> - A private repository is visible only to its owner and users that owner gives permissions to. This means an unauthorized user cannot clone or view the contents of a private repo even if they know the repo's URL.
>
> Repository owners can grant other users explicit access to the repository.
>   An owner can allow 5, 10, 25, 50, or an unlimited number of users access to repositories under his or her control.
>   The owner always counts as one user.
>   The owner configures the permissions associated with each user with access.  bitbucket supports the following permission levels:
>
> - **read** View the repository contents.  All public repositories grant all bitbucket users read permissions automatically.
> - **write** Contribute to the repository by pushing changes directly from a repository on a local machine.
> - **admin** Do everything a repository owner can do, except delete the repository.  This means administrators can:
>
>   - Change repository settings.
>   - Add, change, and remove user permissions.
>   - Give other users administrator access.

Comment: I see that my problem was not properly explained. Lets say we have 2 users working on the same repository in different branches. User 1 pushes his changes to the repository, and then clones the repository on the production server. The new repository on the server is now locked to User 1's account, so User 2 doesnt have access to pull his changes. Is there a solution for this perticular situation?

Comment: @frigg that would be through a `post-checkout` hook in order to `chmod` the files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210116/git-deploying-project-file-permissions-chmod (or, for a server, a `post-receive` hook)