# Heroku style GIT deployment for my own server

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, gitosis

How can I install Heroku-style deployment using GIT (gitosis-admin tool)? I use Capistrano for my rails projects but I also have some PHP projects. I would like to setup automated GIT deployment for my projects where the deployment is executed when pushing to master branch.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano can be used for deployment of PHP projects too.

You can use Git `post-commit` hook for deployment after each commit.