# using Git as website backup tool

Tags: php, git

I would like to set up Git to work on my site so I can can

1. I have a repo on my computer (`index.php`, `contact.php`, etc)
2. Set up my webserver (hostgator) so that I can commit to the server
3. Make it so that when I commit, the website's code changes as that's the code I'm working on

All the tutorials that I saw show how to push it onto github which is not what I'm looking for. Also I don't want and git files to be viewable because it contains some PHP passes and stuff in them.

I plan on having different projects on my site. So for now there's one subfolder like /forums that have all the files for that but later I may create another project so I'll make each folder into it's own repo.

Are there any tutorials or video tutorials on how to do this? Any blogs or such? I jest need a nudge in the right direction

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploy a project using Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have SSH access to your web server.

1. Connect to your webserver using SSH, and create the initial
   repository there (`git init`).
2. Then, clone this repository in your computer (`git clone`).
3. Add the website files into the repository (`git add`), and commit
   (`git commit`). Commits in git are always local. You need to
   **push** them to the remote repo. So...
4. Push your changes to the webserver repository (`git push`)
5. To "checkout" these changes automatically to your website, you need
   to add a post-receive hook (see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Answer (score 0):

A quick google for "git on webserver" gave me http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto, which looks like roughly want you want.

I don't believe you need to have `git` on the remote webserver, just `ssh` access. If HostGator provides this, you're golden.