# Setting up Git with existing Live & Testing Sites

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have two sites at the moment:
testing.example.com
and 
www.example.com

(they mostly contain Joomla installs)

How do I set up Git so that I can easily push from testing to live (or live to testing if I want to recalibrate?)

Thanks!

Comment: Are they on the same server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up two repositories on your server and configure them both as remotes on your development machine. Now you can push to your test and live environment however you like.

You might want to set up automatic deployment for those repos. See here how to do that: [Deploy a project using Git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git-push)

Comment: Embarrassingly enough I seem to already have the .git folders with all of their subfolders on both servers. I simply do not know how to properly use them.

Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/LJp5c.png

Comment: what exactly is your problem? How do you access those servers?

Comment: That's the thing. At the moment, I access them through FTP. Which doesn't seem to be the way to use git (of course.) All I want to learn is how to properly use git on this server. But since my experience is mostly front-end, it's a bit difficult to understand.

Comment: I ended up using git gui on Windows and mapped to the server locations.

Comment: Not yet - but I'll make sure to let you know when it is.

Comment: I strongly recommend to always use the command line client – that’s the only way you will actually understand how git works.

Comment: Thanks. It's the hard way - so I was going to skip it, but if you say it's the only way to **understand** it - I'll use it through the command line.