# push git repository to server

Tags: git

I've committed many things into my local repository and even pushed things to shared repositories saved online with team members. I now am looking for a way to store the files that I have on my html directory on my server into my online git, which I can then share with my local repository, and when I make changes locally to automatically commit and push to the remote site in turn updating my server files. Currently I'm using Coda to ssh the files over automatically to the server every time I hit save.

I recently ran into a problem where I accidentally deleted some files on my server during coding, which made me think that had I have git installed I could have just reverted back to a previous date! so without further ado I really would like to implement something like this.

I have done some research on how I could push to my remote repository on the server and found this this tutorial, 
[tutorial link](http://caiustheory.com/automatically-deploying-website-from-remote-git-repository)

But I have an amazon EC2 instance and I am not sure how to run the command line on server which is what I assume I have to do in step one of the tutorial where I need to create a git on the server directory

could anyone give me some guidance on how to do this effectively so that all works well in the end?

Comment: `In distributed version control, push is the action of sending local changes to a remote repository.` So, how do you push into your local repo?? The description is very vague.. Maybe you need to read some basic tutorials on git to understand better how does it work.

Comment: @Kan: Do you understand my question? I would like to create a repository containing my server files. the files should be editable in my local folder, once these files have been edited, i would then push my changes, and these changes would be synced to the server. that is what i am trying to do. If you could now read my post again and maybe you'll understand where I'm stuck at. Thanks kan

Comment: @Pavan Any chance that you mix up the words *push* and *commit*? Committing locally and pushing to a shared repo makes more sense to me.

Comment: @iltempo: ah yess!!!! im sorry for using the wrong word! commit locally... and then when syncing should push onto my server... thus updating my files on my server! using git would allow me to revert etc and keep a track of code changes. Do you have a solution? or could you help me with the setup please? thanks iltempo for correcting me!

Comment: @iltempo: any chance you could help dude?

Comment: As you describe this, it is the main use case of a source control system - make changes in one place, push them to another. Not sure why you have difficulties with it.

Comment: Kan i believe i have difficulties in setting up git on my EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tutorials around. One pretty interesting (because of it's ease) is been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git-push). It basically uses a git hook to update the code on your EC2 instance by pushing to a specific remote repository.

All you need it ssh access to the server and git installed there.

Comment: hey yes.... right so i do need git installed there! one my problems was how to get git installed there. i will check your tutorial now