# The proper way to deploy (by git) zf2 application with vendor modules added by git

Tags: git, zend-framework2

I wanna deploy by git my application to the host.
But if I push my code to repository, in the repo I do not have some of vendor modules (I added them by composer in my local test host).
Is it something with .gitignore in vendor modules ? (Especially with zfc-twitter-bootstrap and zf-commons).
What is the proper way or good practice to deploy by git my application and get submodule added in repo.
(On gitweb a have: "Reading blob failed." in the place of module files).
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: This answer is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git-push#327315 You only need to add a "composer install" command to your bash script (git post-recieve hook)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at `Capistrano`:

http://tfountain.co.uk/blog/2009/5/11/zend-framework-capistrano-deployment

Pushing binaries like vendors into Git is generally not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

`composer install` is the good way.
But don't forget to include composer.lock in your git repo.

[A good explanation can be read here](http://adamcod.es/2013/03/07/composer-install-vs-composer-update.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+adamcodes+%28Adam+Codes%29)

And you could do a `composer dump-autoload --optimize` for an optimal autoloader.

Comment: Ok.. so you guys think, that I should deploy my application using 'git push' to the host as it is (with ignored some of the modules from vendor) and fire composer install on my production server, am I right ?

Comment: If git is the only option, yes. (Capistrano is very good tool). You push a release tag on your repo, and you checkout this tag on production, then `composer install`.

Comment: All right.. great thanks for the advices, I'll try to test them.
Host admin tried to fire composer install and got error 'Could not scan for classes inside'. That stopped us.

Comment: Ok. I've started using zfdeploy.phar (https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-deploy) It's really good stuff.
Thanks for advices guys.