# Using Git for both version control and writing changes to remote server

Tags: git, remote-access

I'd like to use git as following:

I have a repository on **local** machine where I do changes in code. And I have a **remote** server, where this code should run.

I've installed and set up `msysgit` and it is running fine: clones reps, connects to ssh and so on.

But I'm stuck at one issue: how do I make simple cloning of local repository to remote server so I could just `git push` my changes in code later on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploy a project using Git push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git-push)

Comment: Martin, I've read the question you've provided. But I don't get one thing than: why do we need clone at all in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the article, which in details describes how to make what I was asking in the question above. It is about how to both control versions and deploy content to remote server:

http://danbarber.me/using-git-for-deployment/