# How to push local existing folder to remote server via git on windows?

Tags: django, git

Before I install git, I have a local folder `/c/kuaipan/Django/exam` and a remote server whose ip is `111.11.111.11` and username is `root`. Now I just want push all contents of `exam` to server `/home/mygit`.

So I first create a bare repository `/home/git` on server then create a repository for loacal `exam` and push it to server. The infomation seems to be all right. I use `ls` hoping to see there is a `exam` folder or contents of it in `mygit` but there isn't. So what should I do? Where I am wrong.(my git username is "xiangnan" and git email is "280145668@qq.com").

Here is what I try:

```
# remote server
root@remoteuser:/home# cd mygit
root@remoteuser:/home/mygit# git --bare init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/mygit/

# local
Administrator@localuser /c/kuaipan/Django/exam (master)
$ git remote add origin ssh://root@111.11.111.11/home/mygit
Administrator@localuser /c/kuaipan/Django/exam (master)
$ git push -u origin master
root@111.11.111.11's password:
Counting objects: 175, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (167/167), done.
Writing objects: 100% (175/175), 418.90 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 175 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://root@111.11.111.11/home/mygit
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.

# remote server
root@remoteuser:/home/mygit# ls
bin       config       HEAD   include  lib      refs
branches  description  hooks  info     objects
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, bare repositories don't include a working copy. They're effectively just `.git/` directories.

If you want your code to be automatically deployed when you push, you should look into setting up a deploy hook, as described in [Deploy a project using Git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git-push).